# How to Uninstall Windows8 and replace it by WindowsXP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, bios, multi-boot

I want to go back from windows8 to windowdsXp, i want to completely remove Windows8 because i failed to dual boot the both of them in a separate partition .
Please how to do because i'm stacked .
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need a program called **GParted**. To get GParted go over to [Ubuntu page and download the OS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on a CD/DVD. After that you can [boot from the CD/DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) on Ubuntu and try it out. There you can select the tool [GParted Partition Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) which is preinstalled on Ubuntu liveCD and delete with it the partition Windows 8 is on. Afterwards you can install on that same partition you deleted Windows 8 the Windows XP OS.

Comment: Thank you very much,have you any tutorial for that?

Comment: i found that http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Gparted

Comment: Yes, click on the links above i put in my post. Also as i see you don't need to put Ubuntu on CD/DVD you can just put GParted on LiveCD. You need just to download the .iso file and put it on CD/DVD. Just check the links i gave you

Comment: thank you very much i will test it and let you know if that's working

Comment: He could also just download the gparted live disc and use that, less clutter, straight to the point, smaller and will load up faster.

Comment: I downloaded Gparted and i installed it on a usb but when i reboot the PC nothing happend and i log in to the usual Windows8 session, even when i changed the settings and i force it to boot from usb in : SETTINGS->GENERAL->ADVANCED

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi when your PC is starting hit the F8 key. Or read the manual of your PC how to boot. Search on the internet.

Comment: i did that but doesent work, the pc run always to windows8

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi there must be a way to boot your PC. The most common is to keep pressing F8 or F12 or F5 while your PC is starting up. Put the CD in the CD drive and close your PC and then start it up and start hitting the key. Look Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5DeLLXd5gs and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIwPYy4Sigo

Comment: i said i had already access to the boot menu, but even when i change the boot priorities and i restart it always he goes directly to windows8

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi maybe you installed the GParted Tool wrong, check here the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Comment: no i don't think so i did it via the usb and the cd but no changes